# Getting the columns to displays month instead of tuples when using pivot_table method

Tags: python, pandas

pivot a dataframe using this line:

[image]

```
month_df = pd.pivot_table(loadexpense_df,index="Category",columns="Month",aggfunc={"Month":len}, fill_value=0)
```

The end result as display below:
[image]

Q1: How do I write a logic to change the column name ('Month,'Apr) to Apr only and to the rest of column headers?

Q2: Also can pivot table return only the month as header (eg: Apr, May, etc) instead of the tuple (eg: ('Month,'Apr), ('Month,'Aug), etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting result of `pd.pivot_table()` function you get a Dataframe with a columns which represents `MultiIndex` with two levels. You can solve both of your problems by setting second level of your `MultiIndex` to Dataframe column labels:

```
month_df = pd.pivot_table(loadexpense_df,
                          index="Category",
                          columns="Month",
                          aggfunc={"Month":len}, 
                          fill_value=0)

month_df.columns = month_df.columns.get_level_values(level=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Table column-names is contained in `month_df.columns`, and they are iterable. So:

```
columns = month_df.columns
tmp = []
for col in columns:
    if len(col) == 2:
        tmp.append(col[1]) #Taking second tuple-value
    else:
        tmp.append(col)

month_df.columns = tmp #Reassigning columns
```

Q2: I was unable to reproduce your issue with the code given. Mine printed out just fine from the beginning, but I still answered Q1 as I could generate it by hand. But the code

```
month_df = pd.pivot_table(
    loadexpense_df,index="Category",
    columns="Month",aggfunc={"Month":len},
    fill_value=0)
```

Gives me only the name of the months as column-names, and not a tuple.